# fancybox open window 10 seconds after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox, lightbox

I have this script that will do some things if the user clicks on a button.

```
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                          $('.bouton').click(function () {
                            document.getElementById('iframe').src = ...........';
                            $('#bouton').text('$debut');
                            window.setTimeout(\"location=('download_zip_file_link.zip');\",5000);
                            return false;
                          });
                        });
                    </script>
```

I'm trying to open a fancybox2 window to display inline text but i want it to open 10 seconds after the button is clicked. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right idea with [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //code to open fancybox    
  $.fancybox.open("my inline text",{
      // fancybox API options here
  });         
}, 10000);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7GwN9/)

check the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the API options

Comment: ok but what is the code to launch fancybox inside this function ? i only know how to launch it from a link